# C言語でファイル読み込みの方法

Tags: c

```
入力される値
2
2 5
3 4

期待する出力
hello = 2 , world = 5 
hello = 3 , world = 4
```

の場合のコードは、

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
  int i, n;
  char buf[1000];
  char token1[100], token2[100];

  fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
  sscanf(buf, "%d\n", &n);
  for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
    sscanf(buf, "%s %s\n", token1, token2);
    printf("hello = %s , world = %s\n" ,token1 ,token2);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

このように、決まったフォーマットのデータを読み込む際はsscanfとfgetsを組み合わせると、上手くいきますが、
入力されるフォーマットが以下のように不規則の場合、sscanfとfgetsを組み合わせてファイルを読み込むことはできるのでしょうか？（全てint型）

```
入力フォーマット   
M N  
c_1  
c_2  
...  
c_M
a_{1,1} a_{1,2}  ... a_{1,M}  
a_{2,1} a_{2,2}  ... a_{2,M}  
...  
a_{N,1} a_{N,2}  ... a_{N,M}

入力例１
3 3
250
500
1000
100 200 300
30 250 0
1 1 1000

入力例2
5 1
123
456
789
111
220
10 10 10 10 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

横方向のときもscanfが使えます。

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int a[10];
int main()
{
    int i, j, n;    
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) scanf("%d", a+i);
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) printf("%d\n", a[j]);
}
```

入力例は、

```
3
1 2 3
```

です。3つ読めました。

sscanfを使うときは、

```c
int a[10];
int main()
{
    int i, n, len;
    char s[20], t[10], *p = s;

    fgets(t, 10, stdin);
    sscanf(t, "%d", &n);

    fgets(s, 20, stdin);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char s2[5];
        sscanf(p, "%s", s2);
        sscanf(s2, "%d", a+i);
        len = strlen(s2);
        p+=len+1; // スペース１こ
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%d\n", a[i]);
}
```

です。
sscanfでは、ストリームではなく文字列から読み取るので、自分で読み取り位置を調整する必要があります。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。この回文はsscanfの場合も同様に行うことができるのでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決できました！

Answer (score 2):

rueさんが`sscanf`を使った回答をされていますが、もう少しきれいに書けます。[`scanf`系](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)にはそれまでに読み込んだ文字数を返す`%n`があります。これを使うことで一旦`%s`で切り取り長さを調べる必要がなくなり、直接`%d`で数値を取得できます。 [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nMXnk3hog0wVznRo)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char buffer[256], *p;
    int n, *data;
    fgets(buffer, 256, stdin);
    sscanf(buffer, "%d", &n);
    data = calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    fgets(buffer, 256, stdin);
    p = buffer;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int read;
        sscanf(p, "%d%n", data + i, &read);
        p += read;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d\n", data[i]);
    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！参考にさせていただきます！！

Answer (score 0):

一般的には、1行のデータを読み込んで、頭から1文字ずつチェックし、それが数字かスペースか、CR、LFかを判定し、それぞれに適切な処理を行っていくことになると思います。

Comment: 上記の入力フォーマットのように、列がMの値に依存する場合はどのようにして読み込むことができるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

その区切るフォーマットがきちんと定義されているならばどうとでもなります
＃sscanf を使うかどうかは別の話として

Comment: 上記の入力フォーマットのように、列がMの値に依存する場合はどのようにして読み込むことができるのでしょうか？

Comment: Mの値とはどういうことでしょうか。そこらへんを詳しく説明しましょう

Comment: 失礼しました。上記の入力フォーマット内の変数Mです。フォーマット下部のa_{1,1} a_{1,2}  ... a_{1,M}  
a_{2,1} a_{2,2}  ... a_{2,M}  
...  
a_{N,1} a_{N,2}  ... a_{N,M}は列がMの値に依存しています